Run portion of code without debug code attached during debug session
I have the following code:
void abc()
{
    method A; //(time consuming)
    method B; 
}

When pressing F5 in visual studio to debug this c# code, I need to run method A before method B because the result of it is pass to method B. i just want to debug method B. I'm 100% sure method A is working fine.
How can i run method A without debug code as its time consuming?

Put breakpoint on or before a and use your mouse to drag the yellow arrow in the margin past A and drop it on line B. Or right click on B and choose Set Next Statement or something like that?

Thanks for your reply. i have just tried your method  but when i drag it to B, A will not be executed ?

Yes it won't. With all the consequences. If B uses a result from A or depends on a side effect, then it will probably fail.

Anyhow: I would strongly suggest you get accustomed to Unit Testing. That way you single out B's code, give it consistent input and assert consistent output.

Run A and save its output, either to a file or directly in your test setup code. Then you can run B in the debugger as many times as you like passing B the saved output from the single run of A.

Oh, I misunderstood, because your code didn't look like there was any dependence between the method eg  var x = methodA(); methodB(x); I missed the part where method A produces something that method B needs. Get method A to produce whatever thing it does and save it, then load it and call B with it, using that saved result instead ..

Post your actual code, not this pseudocode
